# sql select join view

Tags: sql, join, view, sqlite

Given a table of id, 'points' and coordinates, would like to create a view (i think it'd need to be a view) such that i can get a list of distances between all 'pointids' for two given (foreign key) ids

input table

```
pointid (key), foreign_key, x, y
01,            id_x,        6, 2,
71,            id_x,        6, 1,
02,            id_y,        5, 9,
34,            id_z,        3, 8
42,            id_z,        2, 3,
```

desired view, get the distances between all points belonging to id_x and id_y:

```
pointid_1,     pointid_2, distance
01,            02,        12 (or whatever distance is between 6,2 and 5,9)
71,            02,        12 (or whatever distance is between 6,1 and 5,9)
```

another query would be, the distances between all points belonging to id_x and id_z:

```
01,            34,        33 (distance between 6,2 and 3,8)
01,            42,        nn
71,            34,        nn
71,            42,        nn
```

etc

I can do the distance computation sqrt(....) , but do not know how to do the join and combine that with the distance computation, or what the appropriate query of such a view would be to produce the above results.

this would be using sqlite3 with loaded math lib extensions for the distance calc

Comment: How do you order points along the way? Once you figure how to separate a 'route' in your points and order points along it, create a view that for each point gives its 'next' point. For the last point, the next point would be the last point itself (zero distance). Then calculating and summing distances will be straightforward.

Comment: not sure i follow. the aim is not to find a 'route' along the points, just to get the distance between each point, for two ids. ultimatley the query would be ordered by distance, but not try and determine a route along the points. im thinking its a cartesion product but not 100% sure what that is exactly.

Comment: If you only need distance between each pair of points, not a distance along a route (as I thought), you just join the table with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create view PAIRWISE_DISTANCE_SQUARES as
select 
  a.id as a_id,
  b.id as b_id,
  (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y) as square
from point_table as a, point_table as b
-- where a.id != b.id if you wish
```

This view will give you squares of distances between points. SQLite does not have a `sqrt`, but squares are as fine for sorting as actual distances.

Comment: thanks that's what i'm after. and good point about the squares doing the job I hadn't thought of that. _actually also needs the 'foreign keys' columns in the view but I get it from here_